# Get Post ID after front end post submission

Tags: front-end, wp-insert-post

I can't get the published post ID, i'm using a front end custom form. When the submit button is clicked site is re directed to a different page. Now, i can't get the just published post ID using:

`wp_insert_post($post)`

Because it returns the ID of redirected page instead of the published post. How can i get it? I'm running in circles here.

Comment: I'm am unsure what you mean. `wp_insert_post()` should return the actual created post. Can you explain further?

Answer (score 1):

`wp_insert_post()` returns either one of three things

- the newly created post's ID
- a `WP_Error` object if `$wp_error` is set to true if an error occured during post insertion in which case the post is not inserted
- `0` if `$wp_error` is set to false (*default*) if an error occured during post insertion in which case the post is not inserted

The following should work

```
$args = [
    // All your post arguments
];
$q = wp_insert_post( $q );
if (    0 != $q 
     && !is_wp_error( $q )
) {
    echo 'My new post ID is ' . $q;
}
```

Comment: Hi, yes this works. But my post is generated from a function in the functions file. I'm developing a three steps reservations process and the form takes the user through each step, form 1 takes user to form 2 and that one takes the user to form 3. The form uses the function and when redirections happens the `$q` returns the ID of the actual page.

I get help from other site, the correcto way to achieve this is to declare this in the redirected page (in my case is a template):

`if( $_POST) {
 $p = name_of_my_function();
}`

Comment: You should make sure that you post all relevant stuff in your question. I have answered what was given in your question, I could never know the extra details you posted. Please be sure that you post **all** relevant info next time so you can get specific answers to your exact problem

Answer (score 0):

I am using a `custom_function()` to insert the post, the form redirects the user to a different page, that page has it's own ID and that's why I couldn't get this to work.

In my case worked declaring this in my template:

```
if( $_POST) {
    $post_ID = custom_function();
}
```

Then i can use `$post_ID` to get the custom data I needed from that post.